# how can i create fake input in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I need to create a fake input so that i can change the content to be html elements.

Like in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) app you can type something like : `a^b` and it will change to a<sup>b</sup> witch in html is:`a<sup>b</sup`.

Also see the [Monaco Editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html) that does syntax highlighting, autocomplete, etc.

I am familiar with `contenteditable` attribute but in Demos they don't use it.

in both of these applications they implementing a fake input without using text area
, hidden input, or `contenteditable` attribute.

So my question is how to achieve that behavior and implement a fake input 
with fake oninput, onblur, oncopy etc handler functions.

Comment: It looks as if they have an onfocus of the element which then kicks of a onkeyup function which will read your keystrokes and depending on what you press, they add attributes to a span (which in turn must populate the html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use keydown/keyup/keypress events for edit content in your fake-field. 
Something like this:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if($(e.target).is("#your_editor")) {
        // editor area focused
        if($(this).hasClass("focused")) {
            return;
        }
        $(this).addClass("focused");
    } else {
        // editor area is not focused
        $("#your_editor").removeClass("focused");
    }
});

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    // some key are pressed
    if($("#your_editor").hasClass("focused")) {
        // do something with e.keyCode
    }
});
```

Comment: By the way Monaco Editor are using textareas!

Comment: True, didn't see that until now.
it is storing the raw value of the editor.
but still i cant think of a way to implement the events right.

Comment: You can catch clicks on each line, than add textarea to cursor position.